# Text to speech stopped speaking but loop to pause does not stop

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to add pause and play functionality in tts. what is have done so far is, when i stop tts speaking and want to get the last spoken word but the loop which is running not getting stop. please resolve my problem.

```
 public void toggleAudioMode() {
    isPlayerVisible = !isPlayerVisible;
    ivToggleAudioModeAnswer.setImageResource(isPlayerVisible ? R.drawable.ic_audio_off : R.drawable.ic_audio_on);
    if (isPlayerVisible) {
        splitspeech = result.split(" ");
        if (j > 0) {
            speakSpeech(j, "run");
        } else {
            speakSpeech(0, "run");
        }
    } else {
        keepGoing = false;
        speakSpeech(0, "stop");
    }
}

 public void speakSpeech(int m, String type) {
    myHash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "done");

    while (i < splitspeech.length) {
        if (type.equals("run")) {
         if (i == 0) { // Use for the first splited text to flush on audio stream
          textToSpeech.speak(splitspeech[i].trim(), QUEUE_FLUSH, myHash);
            } else { // add the new text on previous then play the TTS
          textToSpeech.speak(splitspeech[i].trim(), QUEUE_ADD, myHash);
                j = i;
            }
        } 
        i++;
    }
    if (type.equals("stop")) {
        textToSpeech.stop();
    }
}
```

i want play and pause functionality.

Comment: if (type.equals("run")) { 
}else  if (type.equals("stop")) {}

should work.

Comment: I have also used this but the problem still remain.